# Remix IDE getting VM error invalid opcode

Tags: solidity, remix, metamask, dapps, ide

I am attempting to deploy a test contract on javascriptVM using Remix IDE in chrome. However when I try to execute the contract I receive this message in the status section.

> "transact to Notes.addNote errored: VM error: invalid opcode. invalid
>   opcode        The execution might have thrown.    Debug the transaction to
>   get more information. "

pl let me know if anything wrong in mycode..

Comment: can you provide full code here in question?

Comment: Are you adding the first note in the contract? Also adding the error string in `require` statements can be helpful to debug.

Comment: I think you are getting mixed up in note_id and index of array, if note at a particular index is not even created, how can you assign value directly by `=`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Invalid opcode can be the result of either one of the following runtime operations:

1. `assert` of an expression which evaluates to `false`
2. `array[i]` where `i >= array.length`

In your code, only the second option appears viable.

It is viable in the expression `userNotes[msg.sender][_noteId]`.

So the error must be the result of `_noteId >= userNotes[msg.sender].length`.

Comment: Two more operations which can lead to invalid opcode: 1. Dividing by zero. 2. Calling a function which receives an enum parameter as input, and passing it a value larger than that enum's max value. This is a rather poor decision of the Solidity compiler development team, since this scenario can be the result of user input (i.e., calling the function from the off-chain), which means that the correct opcode should be Revert (and the user would subsequently receive the remaining gas back). I hope that they change this decision in the future.

Comment: As a follow up, in 0.8.0 all of these were changed to revert with an error code.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably because there are some array iterables which are going out of range.
Invalid opcode error comes only in this case (For me though).

New to blockchain and smart contracts!!! Correct me if I'm wrong.