# Execution erorr: Invalid opcode on estimateGas | Possible unhandled promise rejection

Tags: solidity, contract-development, react, gas-estimate

**pragma solidity ^0.5.0;**

I get invalid opcode error when trying to estimate gas needed for my transaction from react-native using the following line of code:

```
const gasAmount = await contract.methods
      .Track(RecordOwner, account, meidcalRecordHash)
      .estimateGas({from: account});
```

After some searching, I found [this answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/66451), which states that `invalid opcode` can be the `result` of `either` one of the following `runtime operations`:

(1)`assert` of an expression which evaluates to `false`

(2)`array[i]` where `i >= array.length`

However, I do not see any of these two possible runtime operation in my **solidity "Track" function**

```
   function Track(
        address _patientID,
        address _doctorID,
        string memory _recordHash
    ) public {
        

        // Get the record hash index
        uint256 i;
        uint256 recordHashIndex;
        string[] memory patient_recordHashes = getPatientRecordHashes(
            _patientID
        );

        for (i = 0; i < patient_recordHashes.length; i++) {
            // CHANGED count to patient_recordHashes.length
            string memory patient_recordHash = patient_recordHashes[i];
          
            if (
                keccak256(abi.encodePacked(patient_recordHash)) ==
                keccak256(abi.encodePacked(_recordHash))
            ) {
                recordHashIndex = i;
            }
        }

        // Get the doctor address index
        uint256 doctorIndex;
        address[] memory patient_listOfDoctors = getPatientRecordListOfDoctors(
            _patientID,
            recordHashIndex
        );
        for (i = 0; i < patient_listOfDoctors.length; i++) {
            if (patient_listOfDoctors[i] == _doctorID) {
                doctorIndex = i;
            }
        }
      

        // Set the bool value corresponding to the "recordHashIndex" & "doctorIndex" to true
        IsRecordSeen[_patientID][recordHashIndex][doctorIndex] = true;

        // Destroy/remove the medical record from the dcotor view screen
        delete patientToDoctorRecordNames[_patientID][_doctorID][recordHashIndex];
        delete patientToDoctorRecordHashes[_patientID][_doctorID][recordHashIndex];
        delete patientToDoctorEncKeyHashes[_patientID][_doctorID][recordHashIndex];
    } // end of the Track function



//Some of the function used inside the Track function:

// Get all the record hashes of a patient
    function getPatientRecordHashes(address _patientID)
        public
        view
        userExists(_patientID)
        returns (string[] memory)
    {
        return patientRecordHashes[_patientID];
    }

  // Get the list of doctors with access to a specific medical record of a patient
    function getPatientRecordListOfDoctors(address _patientID, uint256 index)
        public
        view
        userExists(_patientID)
        returns (address[] memory)
    {
        return patientRecordListOfDoctors[_patientID][index];
    }
```

***Is there something wrong inside the Track function that cause invalid opcode ? Any hint would be highly appreciated***

**Update1**: I have just tested the "Track" function on remix. It is working fine. Also, the estimate gas sometimes works, but not all the time. *any hint on why this is happening, please?*

```
const gasAmount = await contract.methods
      .Track(RecordOwner, account, meidcalRecordHash)
      .estimateGas({from: account});
```

**some data structures used :**

```
mapping(address => mapping(address => string[]))
    public patientToDoctorRecordHashes;

mapping(address => mapping(uint256 => address[]))
    public patientRecordListOfDoctors;

mapping(address => string[]) public patientRecordHashes;







mapping(address => mapping(uint256 => bool[])) public IsRecordSeen;
```

**Update2:** Please note  there is also an `"Add" function` that is usually called before the "Track" function. This "Add" function has  multiple "push" operations inside. some of these `push operations` are:

```
    patientRecordHashes[_patientID].push(_recordHash);
    doctorListOfPatients[doctorAddress].push(_patientID);
     patientToDoctorRecordHashes[_patientID][doctorAddress].push( _recordHash);
    IsRecordSeen[_patientID][count].push(false);
```

Comment: BTW, as the user who wrote that answer about invalid opcodes, I can tell you that there is yet one more trigger that can cause them: calling a function which receives an `enum` parameter as input, and passing it a value larger than that enum's max value. This is a rather poor decision of the Solidity compiler development team, but it is nevertheless the current behavior.

Comment: As to your question: The state-variables `patientRecordHashes` and `patientRecordListOfDoctors` are missing in your code. We have no idea what they are (arrays or mappings) and how they are initialized. Obviously, your question cannot be answered without this information!

Comment: Added them above .
    mapping(address => mapping(address => string[]))
        public patientToDoctorRecordHashes;

    mapping(address => mapping(uint256 => address[]))
        public patientRecordListOfDoctors;

    mapping(address => string[]) public patientRecordHashes;

Comment: `However, I do not see any of these two possible runtime operation` - I could not find a single occurrence of `push` in your code (and in this entire webpage to be honest, except for the one that i just mentioned). So obviously every storage array in your code is of length 0. Thus, obviously any attempt to access any of the arrays in your contract would result with an invalid opcode, **exactly** as stated in the 2nd bullet in the answer that you've quoted!

Comment: A generic way to see if the opcode invalid is in the code is to look at the assembly output  of the function. You can do this by `solc --asm`. The output should have comments that denote entry point of your function.

Comment: @goodvibration I did not include the whole smart contract. However, please note that is an "Add" function that is usually called before the "Track" function. This "Add" function has multiple "push" operations, which are added above in update#2 for your reference.

Comment: @goodvibration BTW, Also, I am using Solidity 5.0.0 and web3 1.2.9. Could the "invalid opcode" be due to the web3 or solidity version ?